# My views are invisible or at best obscured

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

My main.xml declares some views:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send SMS"> 
 </Button>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="3.144214421442144214421442144214421442" />
```

...and the constructor for my main Activity sets the GUI to the main.xml:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

but when I run the app in the emulator, I don't see these views (button, textView, mapView) - instead I see a google search bar near the top, and the friendly green fella advising me, "Drag apps to your Home screen..."

Is this a familiar scenario to anyone out there in android-land?

Comment: are layout are your views in??

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using a LinearLayout.  The MapView has 'fill_parent' for height.  You should set that to 'wrap_content' with a layout_weight of 1.

Comment: Thanks, but I still just get the generic emulator, as if my app isn't running (probably because it isn't).

Maybe this has something to do with it:

[2011-11-12 16:43:18 - WRYReq] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2011-11-12 16:43:18 - WRYReq] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-11-12 16:43:18 - WRYReq] Launch canceled!

?

Yet the app appears to run - at least the emulator starts up...?

Comment: I think I'd have to see more code to comment on what's happening.